# Kernel PCA vs. k-means

Tags: machine-learning

Could someone compare k-means and kernel PCA in the domain of vector quantization (memory, speed, effectivity, ...)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Kernel PCA is a dimensionality reduction/visualisation algorithm, it isn't really suitable for vector-quantization.  For a kernel approach to vector quantisation, see the paper by [Tipping and Scholkopf.](http://www.gatsby.ucl.ac.uk/aistats/aistats2001/files/tipping140.pdf).  The example where you can still read the registration number of the car for the kernel algorithm, but not with the LBG algorithm (similar to k-means), is really neat (figure 2).

Comment: ok and can you compare it in the case of dimensionality reduction/visualisation? or just basically compare their memory/computational requirements, difficulties with optimal parameter estimation, etc.?

Comment: just to check, is this a homework/assignment question?

Comment: no, it is not a howework/assignment - semester is already over :)

Comment: I'd just like to know pros/cons, basic principles are quite clear to me...

Comment: kernel algorithms generally have memory requirements scaling as O(n^2) (for storage of kernel matrix) and computational expense as O(n^3) (for inversion or eigendecomposition of said kernel matrix), where n is the number of patterns.  This can be a good thing if you have many more features than patterns though.  k-means is a clustering algorithm, so no use for visualisation if the data isn't clustered.  K-means has memory requirements O(n).  For a kernel visualisation algorithm that incorporates clustered data, see this paper http://doi.ieeecomputersociety.org/10.1109/TPAMI.2007.70819

Comment: Thank you very much for your answer. Could you please, give me some comment on selecting of a "good" kernel? Is it still an open question, or is it already solved? How is it with the degrees of freedom? It the case of k-means, it's quite clear, how is it with kpca?

Comment: For supervised methods, cross-validation is generally a robust method, although you can get over-fitting if you optimise the cross-validation error too much (see e.g. http://jmlr.csail.mit.edu/papers/v11/cawley10a.html) especially if there are many degrees of freedom (kernel parameters).  This can probably be made to work with kpca (especially fully probabilistic versions), but I haven't used KPCA in anger.